# Wordpress: Should I use a function or a global variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello :) I'm just learning Wordpress and I can not find an answer to a question about how to write code.

Here is my code:

```php
if ( !function_exists( 'mythemename_social_sites_list' ) ) :

  function mythemename_social_sites_list() {

    return [
      [ 'name' => 'Twitter', 'icon'  => 'fab fa-twitter' ], 
      [ 'name' => 'Facebook', 'icon' => 'fab fa-facebook-f' ], 
      [ 'name' => 'Google Plus', 'icon' => 'fab fa-google-plus-g' ], 
    ];

  }

endif;
```

In general, the function returns many more elements of the array, but here I gave only 3 to be more visible. What's the problem?

Is there any sense to write it this way? In a sense, a function that returns an array but **does nothing** with it? From what I understand, functions should be used when they do something. For example, this one would take an array, then do something with it and return the changed one.

Would not it be better to just write this:

```php
global $mythemename_social_sites_list;

$mythemename_social_sites_list = [
  [ 'name' => 'Twitter', 'icon'  => 'fab fa-twitter' ], 
  [ 'name' => 'Facebook', 'icon' => 'fab fa-facebook-f' ], 
  [ 'name' => 'Google Plus', 'icon' => 'fab fa-google-plus-g' ], 
];
```

Global, because I use this array in several places.

Thanks in advance for the brightening :)

Comment: I'm not very well versed with WP but since there's nothing really going on in your function but return a value, better use global variable then.

Comment: A function or a class. Using a global variable, you would need to declare it global in every function / method you use before you can use it. Using a function or a class, it is easy to test and to track down where it comes from. And you can use it everywhere.

Comment: Thank you :) So... I think the function will be a better option.